# operator overloading in c++ , could not call the two parameter constructor

Tags: c++

My program requires me to add two rational numbers in C++ using the concept of operator overloading. The program should read the entire line ( eg: 2/3 + 3/4 ) and return the result. The constructor in the program should validate the rational number ( should display an error when you enter 0 in denominator (eg: 2/0 + 3/4).

I wrote the below program, but I cannot make a call to my two parametric constructor, so the zero parameter constructor is getting executed , and the result of 2 is printed every time. Could anyone please help me with this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

 class rational { 
     int numer;
     int denom;
     int result;

 public:

    rational():numer(1),denom(1) {}

    rational(int a, int b) {
         if(b==0) {
             cout<<"Eror Denominator should be greater than zero";
             exit(0);
         } else {
             numer=a;
             denom=b;
         }
     }

     int gcd(int a, int b);

     friend istream& operator>>( istream  &input, rational &r ) {        
        int x,y; 
        input>>x;
        input.ignore(1);
        input>>y;

        rational(x,y);  // here I am not able to call my constructor
        return input;     
     }

     rational operator+(rational c2) {
         rational temp;
         rational g;

         temp.numer=(c2.numer*denom)+(numer*c2.denom);
         temp.denom=c2.denom*denom;

         result=g.gcd(temp.numer,temp.denom);
         temp.numer=temp.numer/result;
         temp.denom=temp.denom/result;
         return temp;
     }

     friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const rational &r ) { 
         if(r.denom==1) {
             output <<r.numer;
             return output;            
         } else {
             output <<r.numer<<"/"<<r.denom;
             return output;      
         }
     }
 };

 int rational:: gcd(int a, int b) {
    int gc=1;

     for(int i=1;i<=a&&i<=b;i++) {
          if((a%i==0)&&(b%i==0)) {
              gc=i;
          }
      }
     return gc;
}

 int main() { 
     cout.setf(ios::boolalpha);
     string op;

     rational r1;
     rational r2;


    cin>>r1>>op>>r2;
    cout<<(r1+r2)<<endl;  
    int i;
    cin>>i;
 }
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `r = rational(x,y);`?

Comment: when I write the above code ,but it didn't work out

Comment: What goes wrong when you try to call the constructor you want, *exactly*?

Answer (score 0):

Following will simply constructs new `rational` object and destroys, it won't assign your current object

```
 rational(x,y);
```

You need to assign the members of your class in overloaded `<<` operator

```
input >> r.numer >> r.denom;
```

To actually perform validation or your entered data you *could* create separate function, which will be called before performing any calculations

```
 #include <stdexcept>

 bool rational::validate( ) const // private member function
 {
      return denom == 0  ? false : true ;     
 }

 friend istream& operator>>( istream  &input, rational &r )
 {        

      input >> r.numer >>r.denom;

      if( !r.validate () )
             throw std::runtime_error("Bad Input") ;
      return input;

 }
```

You can call this validate in parameterized constructor too. Remember the second constructor will be called when you invoke with argument and use that object.

See [*`here`*](http://rextester.com/VCYBM30135)

Comment: I need the parameterized constructor to be called because that is the requirement and the logic for validation should be specified in the constructor. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

With this statement,

```
rational r1;
```

the default constructor of rational object r1 gets called.

```
rational():numer(1),denom(1)
{

}
```

and you are printing:

```
cout<<(r1+r2)<<endl;
```

so, your result is 2, since default values are set to 1 each.

This does not work the way you expect it to:

```
cin >> r1>> op>> r2;
```

you need to overload the stream operator >> for your object(class) and then add your logic there.

```
 friend istream& operator>>( istream  &input, rational &r )
{ 

     //push the values into object
      input >> r.numer >>r.denom;    
}
```

Comment: I need the parameterized constructor to be called because that is the requirement and the logic for validation should be specified in the constructor. Any solutions?

Comment: when do you want it to be called?? cin>>r1>>op>>r2; or  rational r1;; ??